# Как просто сделать дубль базы данных MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql

Существует ли в MySQL возможность сделать простой дубликат базы данных командами из `Python`-программы?

К примеру, есть база данных `bd1`, содержащая в себе таблицы `t1`, `t2`, `t3`.
Я хочу максимально просто сделать так, чтобы у меня были `bd1` в неизменном виде, и `bd2` (введенное название), с идентичным `bd1` содержимым для дальнейшей работы.

Уточню, что речь идет не о бэкапе, а о получении 2 баз, которые в дальнейшем будут использоваться.

Или же подобное лучше реализовывать в рамках одной базы, но с разными названиями таблиц? Условно каждый раз вместо `bd+1` сделать `t+1`, `t+2`, `t+3`, с прописанными в условной `t0` соответствиями?

Ок, **для XY пишу задачу**:
Есть пользователи python приложения. Для каждого из них должно быть реализовано хранение и дальнейшее использование данных, полученных в результате работы. В данный момент структура данных предполагает хранение в нескольких таблицах.

Ожидается, что со временем, объем данных от каждого из пользователей будет возрастать. И, если на первом этапе еще можно запихать их всех в 1 таблицу со столбиком Username, то в дальнейшем это, предположительно, может привести к значительному увеличению времени выполнения команд, связанных с получением информации из MySQL.

Идея возможной реализации выглядит так:

Каждый раз, когда появляется новый пользователь (кнопка из интерфейса), ему нужно дать свою базу данных, (или) набор таблиц с определенным "нулевым" наполнением, идентичным образцу. В дальнейшем, все команды пользователя выполняются с обращением к его, персональной базе данных/таблице.

Comment: Типичная [XY-проблема](https://xyproblem.info/). Описывайте ЗАДАЧУ, а не то, как Вы её собрались решать.

Comment: *Или же подобное лучше реализовывать в рамках одной базы, но с разными названиями таблиц?* Ни в коем случае. Это - отложенный геморрой.

Comment: В общем случае - только бэкап и последующий рестор в новую БД, с новым именем, может создать полнофункциональную копию существующей БД. А при определённых обстоятельствах - только "ручной" бэкап, с ручной рихтовкой перед рестором.

Comment: вместо столбика username должно бы быть `user_id`. Если не будете нормализовать струкрутуру, то действительно объем данных может вырасти куда быстрее из-за неоптимального хранения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скопировать таблицу

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS SELECT * FROM original_table;
```

или

```
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE original_table;
INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM original_table;
```

Скопировать базу данных сложнее на уровне SQL. Но можно запустить

```
mysqldump .... -p old_database_name |  mysql ... -p new_database_name
```

Оригинальную проблему лучше всего решить партицированием.
https://habr.com/ru/articles/66151/

#### HASH

```
PARTITION BY HASH(store_id)
PARTITIONS 4;
```

Вы никак не управляете партицированием, просто указываете, по какому полю строить хеш и сколько «подтаблиц» создавать. Зачем? Гораздо быстрее происходит выборка по указанному полю. В некоторых случаях позволяет достигнуть «равномерного разброса» и ускорения записи данных.

#### KEY

Почти то же самое что и HASH, но более логично — по ключу.

```
PARTITION BY KEY(s1)
PARTITIONS 10;
```

Т.е. выборка по указанному ключевому полю происходит максимально эффективно.

Comment: Спасибо, я потыкаюсь.

Comment: @Gh0sTG0 делай партицирование - это правильное решение Вашей проблемы. добавил в ответ.